# Why is python telling me 'user input' is not defined

Tags: python

```
guest = []
list = 1

while list != '0':
    name = input('Enter the name of one of your guests: ')
    guest.append(name)
    list = input('if there are no more guests press 0, otherwise press any other key ')

print(' ')
guest.sort()
print guest
```

"""Whenever I enter user input I get the following error "name '(user input)' is not defined."

While searching for similar questions I found the following code which works on other peoples machines, however it gives me a similar error:"""

```
shopList = [] 
maxLengthList = 6
while len(shopList) < maxLengthList:
    item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
    shopList.append(item)
    print shopList
print "That's your Shopping List"
print shopList
```

"""When I enter a list item here I get the following error "name '(user input)' is not defined.

It seems that any time I use the following syntax:
x = input('blahblahblah: ')

I get this error, as far as I can tell I am using the correct syntax, I'm not able to understand what this error means or why I am getting it. Any assistance or explanation is greatly appreciated, thanks."""

Comment: @unutbu: yeah, the linked page explains that.

Comment: Can you post a link to that answer? I couldn't find an answer to this question, thanks

Comment: It's in the yellow box at the top of your question.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, thanks. I'm really new to this.